# finite joint distribution implies infinite joint distribution?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Given an infinite sequence of random variables $(X_n)_{n\geq0}$, all defined on $\Omega$ with range $S$, and supposing that I could compute all joint distributions $$P(\{X_0 = i_0\} \cap \{X_1=i_1\} \cap \cdots \cap \{X_m=i_m\})$$for all $m\geq 0$, could I then compute the infinite joint distribution$$P(\bigcap_{n\geq0} \{X_n = i_n\}) \quad?$$
If no, does it help  if I additionally assume that $(X_n)_{n\geq0}$ is Markov?

Comment: Controversy: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26293/dealing-with-inappropriate-behavior-in-comments

Comment: Seeing the entirely negative approach to the site displayed by this user, I deleted my first comment to them, which was upvoted and was fully addressing their question. If memory does not fail me in these matters, I plan to avoid altogether helping them in the future.

Comment: @Did: Do you think that a significant fraction of the difficulties of askers of probability questions can be explained by lack of adequate background? Most notably not having a proper course on measure theory. I could easily see telcomm engineers and quant-wannabes taking courses in stochastics without hearing about Lebesgue integrals at all. If so, may be we should brainstorm about the best way to handle this problem in meta. I see (engineering/programming) students of cryptography and coding theory asking very confused algebra questions simply because they don't have the background.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen This is an interesting thought (**very** interesting, I mean). At the moment, I have trouble imagining some practical remedies but if something pops up, I should let you know...

Answer (score 4):

Let $E_m$ be the event that $X_k=i_k$ for all $k,0\le k\le m$. Let $E_\infty$ be the event that $X_k=i_k$ for all $k\in\Bbb{N}$. Then

- $E_\ell\subseteq E_m$ whenever $\ell\ge m$, and $E_\infty=\bigcap_{m\in\Bbb{N}}E_m$.
- As all the probabilities are finite, by [the properties of measures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics)#Measures_of_infinite_intersections_of_measurable_sets)
  $$P(E_\infty)=\lim_{m\to\infty}P(E_m).$$

The existence of that limit is a part of the result of continuity of measure from above, but it is also an immediate consequence of the convergence of monotone bounded sequences.

Comment: Trying to put this episode behind us. I am surprised if this is not a (near) duplicate of a question we have handled under the tags of either probability and/or measure theory. If anyone finds an appropriate duplicate target, @-ping me, so I can delete this. I don't frequent either of those tags, so I don't have an idea for good buzzwords for the search engine.